# How can I automatically print different PDFs based on specific contents of emails?

Tags: email, pdf, printing, automation

Basically an if/then script. If an email contains certain text, then print this PDF. Been trying to figure it out but I have zero idea what I'm doing. Happy to do it myself but can't seem to get anywhere, can't even figure out how to start. Terrible, I know.

Any help would be awesome. Even a point in the right direction would be great.

Thank you!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] in **what you have already tried** so as to help you in the direction you are already going.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be an easier way, but the first thing I can think of is
Mail→Settings→Rules→Add Rule
set up your conditions, then the action to take can be Run AppleScript
[image]

Comment: And the required AppleScript is....

Comment: … beyond my expertise.  But OP asked for "even a point in the right direction."